# Android: Can't change view size after setRotation() is called

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a frame layout with TextureVideoView. When I click on fullscreen button I want to hide status bar, rotate TextureVideoView on 90 degrees and stretch it to the height of the screen. The problem I face is that view is easily stretched to the screen width, but not height. I tried everything such as:

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams rootParams = videoRootFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();
        rootParams.height = getScreenWidth();
        rootParams.width = getScreenHeight(); //doesn't stretch
        videoRootFrameLayout.requestLayout();
```

Or

```
clipChildren="false"
```

in root XML layout, however result is always the same:

[image]

It feels like there is a bug in Android itself, since non of solutions solve a problem. Even animation doesn't stretch it to full screen.

Any help would appreciated, since I browsed all similar answers, but non of them helped me.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams rootParams = videoRootFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();
 rootParams.height = getScreenWidth();
 rootParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
 videoRootFrameLayout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Please explain why this line will solve the problem!

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and nothing worked. It simply doesn't stretch regardless the value assigned.